# How to retrieve time in XML

Tags: xml, syntax

In this XML :

```
<CD>
<title>Essential Collection </title>
<artist>Lee Dorsey</artist>
<tracks>
<track>Ya Ya</track>
<track>Do Re Mi</track>
<track>Ride Your Pony</track>
<track>Work Work Work</track>
<track>Can You Hear Me</track>
<track>Get Out Of My Life Woman</track>
<track>Working In A Coalmine</track>
<track>Holy Cow</track>
<track>Operation Heartache</track>
<track>Gotta Find A Job</track>
</tracks>
</CD>
```

CD is Compact Disc. It has different song tracks. I want to calculate total playing time of CD. How I will represent time in XML, in two ways?

Comment: Maybe this is of help to you: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<tracks>
    <track>
        <name>Ya Ya</name>
        <duration>207</duration>
    </track>
    <track>
        <name>Do Re Mi</name>
        <duration>118</duration>
    </track>
    .
    .
    .
</tracks>
```

Comment: Sorry, In order to vote up I must have at least 15 reputations.

Comment: Your answer seems correct.